# Calling AngularJS service methods in all views

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am having the below index.html page which has the main content and other views are called inside ion-nav-view directive based on the ionic route.

```
<body ng-app="index">

<ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable" align-title="center">

    <ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-back-button>

    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button" ui-sref="index.view">
            Home
        </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>

    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button class="button" ng-click="showPopOver($event)">
            Menu
        </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>

</ion-nav-bar>

<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

</body>
```

In my service, I have a method called showPopOver() and I want this to be called in all views as it contains some reusable code.

But I am not able to call the service method in my view. How should I modify my code to enable this?

Comment: On the surface this looks like a `$scope` issue. Does the popover work in `<ion-nav-buttons />`? If so can you also include the controller code.

Comment: Popover works when I keep the ion-nav-buttons inside the individual template views as I have a method showPopOver in the controller which calls the service method.

Comment: But you don't have that same code in the controllers that the ionic router assigns to the loaded views inside `<ion-nav-views />` ?

Comment: You ca't call service method directly from your view, You can call service method directly from controllers only..

Comment: Make a chain to call service method. I mean make a function inside controller, that will call service method. And call your controller method from view..

Comment: @Ved and David: This is an abstract state and other views are replaced in this at run time based on the route. The abstract does not have any controller assinged to it. It does not make sense for me to use the same method in all controllers. I look for a way to use a single method across all places.

Comment: I can solve this issue by putting hte ion-nav-button inside the individual views and call the methode inside the controller which in turn calls the service method as you guys said. But I see it as a code-duplication.

Comment: Your scope could expose the injected service, allowing you to call its methods directly from the view. eg. ng-click="serviceVar.showPopOver($event)"

Comment: @pinoyyid : Could you please explain on this?

Comment: Your controller has an injected instance of the service. If you store a reference to that service on your $scope, then it becomes visible to the view. So  in your controller $scope.myService = MyService; // where MyService was injected to the contructor. In your view, call myService.showPopOver($event).